# In vino veritas

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story

<sub>Somewhere in England in the 12th century</sub>

The Golden Goblet Inn has reported a robbery and needs your investigative skills. Rumor has it that the local blacksmith conducts some shady business practices to accumulate wealth, and his ties to the village guards often make him immune to scrutiny - He is the prime suspect.

The Inn keeper asked you to search his house for the stolen goods. They will keep him drunk in the Inn, so you have more than enough time to retrieve what's been stolen. The blacksmith is notorious for his  bad memory and cryptic speech, so it wouldn't be a surprise if he had hid some clues for himself to remember... certain things. Please do not damage any property.

---

[image: forge]

You arrive at the forge. Unsurprisingly, our bewildered friend forgot to close the front door.

[image: entrance]

As you step foot into this house, your magic-ey senses immediately start tingling and you turn your head to the flame on the dining table.

[image: flame]

You perceive a voice in your head:

> Tell me the five letter code and I shall conjure a key to the chest

You're terrible at lockpicking, so I guess you'll have to play the flame's game. Perhaps the stolen goods are in said chest? If so, you will somehow need to find the correct five letter code. It must be hidden somewhere here! From now on, you actively start searching for clues and inspect all areas of the house closely - In a specific order the flames magically guides you to.

(Click to view large versions)

[image: tools]  [image: food] [image: workplace] [image: attic] [image: backside]

---

Hint for arguably the hardest part of this puzzle:

> The mini-puzzle of a specific letter will require you to use parts of the [Old English Latin Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_Latin_alphabet). This was weakly hinted by the location/year the story takes place, but may nonetheless be a bit evil :)

Hints for each mini-puzzle:

> 1. Cut it out
>  2. (2*6-2)*2
>  3. No trick here
>  4. Subtract _ from _
>  5. Follow

Emergency hints:

> 1. Common letter of _ and _
>  2. Each object on the shelve represents a single letter. Remember hint #1.
>  3. Chains
>  4. You'll need the radish and the markings.
>  5. Start on the odd one out, then draw

---

<sub>**NOTE:** Open `i.stack.imgur.com/XXXXX.jpg` with the five letter code to see if it's correct. The intended image is unmistakable, as it was also photographed in this house.  **First 2 letters are lowercase, last 3 uppercase.**</sub>

<sub>Info: The displayed set is the [Village Forge by BlueBrixx](https://www.bluebrixx.com/en/knights/102000/Village-forge-BlueBrixx-Special).</sub>

Comment: +1 for the LEGOs ;-)

Comment: Is each mini-puzzle supposed to produce a single letter, or lead to a separate imgur link (as implied by the imgur-maze tag)?

Comment: @SQLnoob Just a single letter, poor tagging

Comment: Quick question is the [Village Forge by BlueBrixx](https://www.bluebrixx.com/en/knights/102000/Village-forge-BlueBrixx-Special) just for credits or is it a hint?

Comment: @VarunW. For credits, although you could compare some pictures to find differences.

Comment: I'm honestly confused on how to go about solving this :P

Comment: The blacksmith must be **very** drunk in the inn right now...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having spent already three weeks at the forge, I'm slowly starting to develop a feeling of urgency. While the blacksmith is also notorious for his long drinking benders, anything over three weeks would be a new record even for him. So, I guess it's time to get to work!

What was the first place where the flame guided me again?

> Some tools of the blacksmith! First a hammer and then a shovel?
>
>  Aha! It must be the first letter of hammer and the second letter of shovel, i.e. **H**

And the second place?

> The blacksmith is not really known for his sense of interior decoration, but the placing of those items on the shelf is weird even for him. There must be some code hidden in them. I never learned to read much but at least I remember that there are 24 letters in the [alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_Latin_alphabet), the same number as there are slots on that shelf! Let's see how well i remember those ABC's!
>
>  The red item is on the second letter, so B, then we have D, E, L, O and two items on the U. The items on the chest seem to give us a order for the colours! Taking the letters in that order gives
>
>  **DOUBLE U**!
>
>  I have no idea what that means but just thinking about it makes an unfamiliar shape **W** appear in my head! Kind of looks like two U's? Perhaps I can try calling it a "Double U" for the flame!

Then there was the third place!

> What on earth are those chains doing there? Aha! They clearly form the letter **Y**!

What about the fourth?

> Who keeps radishes in their attic? Clearly it must have some meaning! And then there are those odd scribblings on the chimney: a minus sign, some long hair and S.
>  Hmm,
>  **RADISH - HAIRS = D**, clearly that must be it!

And lastly, the fifth one outside!

> Hmm, looking at that stack of wood, that white birch really doesn't seem to belong? If we start from there and follow the way that the logs seem to point, we get the letter
>  [image]
>
>  **R**!

Finally,

> We have five letters, **hwYDR**! I quickly run back in to tell them to the flame and immediately hear a click as the chest springs open.
>  [image]
>
>  There, it is! The iconic artefact for which the golden goblet is known for! I quickly grab it and head out to bring it back to the inn. While the inn keeper is thankful, he is also not too keen to report his biggest customer to the authorities, so after the blacksmith pays his bar tab, he is just sent home to sober up again. Oh well, at least I did my part!

Comment: The letter positions in the second puzzle are consistent with the first hint (L is 10th, O is 13th, U is 18th).

Comment: for 2), see comment above. 5) makes an uppercase R if you treat the wedge plates as arrows and the circle as stop. 1) "extract" 1st of hammer/ 2nd of shovel (see placement) - I should've changed directions so its atleast "top of hammer", but nonetheless not my proudest idea :)

Comment: @LukasRotter Ah, right, makes sense!